# USB-C to Micro-USB charging adapter - will it be slower?

Tags: usb-3, usb-c

I have a device now that has a USB-C connection but all my old cables are micro-usb, so I picked up a small adapter.  Should I expect to loose much in the way of time to recharge?

Comment: I guess it depends on who made the adapter what its limits are or if it will even work with your phone.

Comment: In order to answer this question, we will need to know the specific part you are asking about.  It does indeed make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two limiters to charging time : how thick the conductors are along the whole chain (thicker is quicker) , and whether the manufacturer exceeds the USB standard for "fast charging".  Apple and Samsung particularly both have unique wall warts, cables, and power supplies on board the mobile device which allow faster charging, but only when approved hardware is in the whole chain.  This is a good idea - unapproved hardware could become too hot and be a fire hazard.  If you were already using generic cables and wall warts, then you probably won't notice a difference.

Answer (score 3):

[Qualcomm Quick Charge](https://www.qualcomm.com/solutions/mobile-computing/features/quick-charge), [Motorola Turbo Power](https://www.motorola.com/us/products/turbopower), [Samsung Adaptive Fast Charging](https://www.samsung.com/global/galaxy/what-is/adaptive-fast-charging/) and [OnePlus Dash Charge](https://www.oneplus.com/global/3t/dashcharge) all require the chipset in the charger to communicate with the phone via USB.

Cheap adapters *may* interrupt this connection, in which case you'll be limited to regular charging speeds.

If the charger you're using isn't enabled with a system to speed up the charging process, you will not notice much difference in the time required to charge the phone, unless the adapter is of *super* low quality and doesn't conduct electricity properly, in which case you should get hold of one which is of a higher quality.